# How to create patches?

Tags: git, patch, git-extensions

I am using Git-Extensions for Windows. I want to create patches from yesterday specific user automatically, so I need command code e.g:

```
git format-patch from date_from to date_to user my_user
```

Is it possible? Command line example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

`git format-patch --author my_user --after 'yesterday midnight' --before 'today midnight' "$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 -n 1 HEAD)"` to generate all that were committed yesterday by my_user.